# How to define a nested has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Suppose we have this contrived model structure

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fruit
  has_one :tree, through: :fruit
  has_one :organism, through: :tree
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tree
  has_many :apples      
end

class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organism
  has_many :fruits
end

class Organism < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trees
end
```

To avoid having to call `@apple.fruit.tree.organism`, I have definded the two has_one-through directives in Apple, and expect `@apple.organism` to work, but it does not. `@apple.tree.organism` does work.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I just define a getter method for :organism on Apple instances and be done with it?

Comment: Normally this will work, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `has_one` technically performs the characteristic of `belongs_to`: think Organism `has_many` apples `through` trees and not the other way around. "belongs_to :through" does not work in Rails, so I suggest using `delegate` in your models.

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :organism, to: :fruit
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :organism, to :tree      
end
```

Comment: I ended up combining a single level :through (to get .tree) and a delegation in Apple (delegate :organism, to: :tree)